# Fatal Error when upgrading to Drupal 7.43

Tags: 7

I'm trying to upgrade from 7.26 to 7.43 but after following the instructions here, /update.php returns a blank page.

When I visit the site homepage, I receive the following error...

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/cr/es/t_/crest-buildingservices.co.uk/public_html/includes/menu.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php52/share/pear:/usr/local/php52/share/php')
>   in
>   /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/cr/es/t_/crest-buildingservices.co.uk/public_html/includes/common.inc
>   on line 5110

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've taken a backup (and, you should have), I would restore and follow the [manual steps](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290) to update Drupal.

Comment: How exactly did you update? You missed a lot of them.

Comment: I followed the instructions at https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290

Comment: I did manage to revert to my backup and have updated all the modules, just need to try updating following the steps again. I'm guessing incrementally updating to a lower version of Drupal would make no difference?